# Squash merging in git keeps including previously-merged branches

Tags: git, github, squash, git-squash

I'm using Github, with branches for `development`, `live` and various feature & bug branches.

When I merge a feature or bugfix into development, I typically do a squash merge (usually through the GH website, although it's equivalent to `git merge --squash branchname`).

Then when I update live from development, I squash merge dev into live.

The benefit of this is the commit message is automatically populated with the list of commits (which, because these were also squashed, is a list of PRs).

The problem I'm having is that when even immediately after merge dev into live, the live branch is still listed as behind development - so next time I merge the two, it includes commits that I know are already merged.

I think what I'm doing is the equivalent to:

1. `git checkout feature/1` & make change
2. `git checkout development`
3. `git merge --squash feature/1`
4. `git commit`
5. `git checkout live`
6. `git merge --squash development` (adds one commit to live)
7. `git commit`
8. `git checkout feature/2` & make change
9. `git checkout development`
10. `git merge --squash feature/2`
11. `git commit`
12. `git checkout live`
13. `git merge --squash development` (adds *two* commits to live - both `feature/1` and `feature/2`)

Why is it not 'completing' the merge and drawing a line under it after step 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "squash merge" is not really a merge. It essentially says "create a patch from these changes, and apply that patch to the target branch". Importantly, it *does not record any relationship with the original commits*.

So, as far as git is concerned, your repository contains three *completely unrelated* commits:

- The original commit on `feature/1` (possibly garbage collected if you delete that branch)
- The commit created on `development` with your first "squash merge"
- The commit created on `live` with your next "squash merge"

As a general rule, you shouldn't carry on using a branch after you've "squash merged" the changes from it - the history on it now represents an "alternative reality" which will never match the target branch. This is probably fine for the original feature branch - you can delete it once it's merged. For `development`, you would have to delete it and then recreate it from `live`; or, equivalently, hard reset it to point at the same commit as `live`.

The straight-forward solution is just not to use a squash merge from `development` to `live`. Either use a true merge (create a merge commit, which *records the relationship* between the merged commits), or a fast-forward merge (re-point `live` at the existing commit in `development`, without creating any new commits at all).

Comment: Is a fast-forward merge equivalent to a rebase and merge?

Comment: @AdamHopkinson Fast-forward is the *second* step of "rebase and merge". You generally don't want to be re-using a branch after a rebase, either - again, it's creating an "alternative reality" with new commits. So by fast-forward I mean *fast-forward only*, which is possible whenever there are no commits on `live` which aren't already on `development`. There are a few questions on here about the different merge types, so I'd encourage you to have a look through some to get a better understanding.